# jquery onchange method or some other method better than onchange

Tags: jquery, html

I have three controls 1)select tag 2)Input tag 3)Input tag.End user makes entries in above three controls.Along with this controls i have other 3 controls where end user does not have chance to make entries ie., they are just readonly.Now the problem is that i have to make ajax call by passing first three controls to  validate whether those values exists in db or not.If all three values exists i have to populate related values into other 3 controls.If does not exists error message.

I thought of using jquery on change method for Last third control of First three fields to send values to db.But it is not good solution there might chance of wrong input for first two fields.

Comment: Can you post some sample code so we can better see what you're working with?

Comment: you've create lookup method base on user controls/input?? I think the best way is used button (let say with name "check") to check their value from DB. for UX purposes, you can add some loading progress to make your user know the system is still work.

Comment: Yes to look up in DB.I have to make it work with out taking button except for submit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could build a timer using `setInterval` that run every 1000/2000ms.

While the timer will run a simple function that check the values of all 3 elements, if anything is changed, then make the ajax call, otherwise, wait for the next check.

```
function IsValuesChanged() {
    if(selVal != $Select.val() || inpVal != $Input.val()) {
    selVal = $Select.val();
    inpVal = $Input.val();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function GetRelatives() {
    // assume ajax called
}

setInterval(function() { if (IsValuesChanged()) GetRelatives(); }, 1500);
```

Try demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7yxkmjfh/